# IIS shows me some junk characters in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using IIS to publish an asp.net web application.
but when I call it in browsers it shows me some additional character before page name
like http://localhost:51690/**(S(qhensvlsl3nkzketvech55eg))**/MainPage.aspx.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is that the server name?

Comment: This looks like the old style of cookieless sessions in WebForms. Either disable sessions or use cookies instead. Do you have `cookieless="true"` in your web.config?

Comment: Thanks so much David. yes it was because of cookieless="true" in web.config.